# Qt migrating from Qt 4 to 5, pri file not included during qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

I am migrating a project from qt 4.8.6 to qt 5.3.2.
I have a pro file which is like this:

```
...
#
# External library configuration
#

include(QGCExternalLibs.pri)

#
# Post link configuration
#

include(QGCSetup.pri)
...
```

and the QGCExternalLibs.pri is simply something like:

```
#
# Add in a few missing headers to windows
#

WindowsBuild {
    INCLUDEPATH += libs/lib/msinttypes \
                libs/thirdParty/opencv/include

    LIBS += -L$$BASEDIR/libs/thirdParty/opencv/x86/vc10/lib

    LIBS += opencv_core231d.lib \
            opencv_highgui231d.lib \
            opencv_video231d.lib \
            opencv_imgproc231d.lib \ 
            opencv_ml231d.lib \
            opencv_features2d231d.lib \
            opencv_flann231d.lib \
            opencv_calib3d231d.lib \
            opencv_objdetect231d.lib \
            opencv_ts231d.lib
}
```

However, when I run qmake -tp vc xxxxx.pro the .pro file is qmaked successfully, however, the .pri file is not included at all. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Worst case - just create a new project, import your sources and copy the libs over from the old one.